# Is it possible to invoke python function with logical statement as parameter?

Tags: python, function, arguments, invocation

I have found a weird function invocation while reading *models.py* file in **python requests** library. I tried to find some explanations in python official documentation but without any successes, unfortunately. Do you possibly know why such a case is possible or how to use logical operators in functions invocation? Are those a part of good practices? Please, find the code below.

```py
fields = to_key_val_list(data or {})
files = to_key_val_list(files or {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of things are used very often in python programming language

```py
fields = to_key_val_list(data or {}) # this means, that if boolean value of data variable is False, use empty dict/or anything you want.
```

Also,,,

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self.data = data or 'abc' # if data will be empty list self.data will become 'abc'
```

You can use and also. and/or both are available.

```py
val = a or b or c # in the chain, if a is False, value of val would become b. if be is False also, then c
val = a and b and c # "and" checks values of whole chain. if a is False, so val will have same value as a. if all is true in chain, the last element value will be inside val.
```